# AngularJS full page refresh on the page I am visting, not the current one

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using maphilight on my main page but if i route to a different partial and then return to that main page, maphilight stops working. However, if I then refresh the page, it works again. how do i force that main page to refresh every time I navigate back to it? I have seen people able to refresh the current page with

```
$scope.reloadPage = function(){window.location.reload();}
```

and

```
<a ng-click="reloadPage()" href="index.html#/diagram">Back to search</a>
```

but I cant get this to refresh the page I am navigating to. thanks in advance

here is the controller for the page I am **linking to** and want to refresh:

```
roomControllers.controller('DiagramController', ['$scope', '$route',  '$http', function($scope, $route, $http) {
$http.get('js/master.json').success(function(data) {
   $scope.rooms = data;
   $scope.reloadPage = function(){window.location.reload();}
});
}]);
```

here is link in the page that I am **coming from**

```
<a ng-click="reloadPage()" href="index.html#/diagram">&laquo; Back to search</a>
```

and here is the app code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
 'ngRoute',
 'roomControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/diagram', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/diagram.html',
    controller: 'DiagramController'
  }).
  when('/diagram/:roomId', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/room-details.html',
    controller: 'RoomDetailsController'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/diagram'
  });
}]);

myApp.directive('highlight', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: $(function(scope, element, attrs) {
          $('img[usemap]').maphilight();
     })};
```

});

and finally the html for the imagemap being highlighted:

```
<div class="info">
  <img ng-src="images/housediagram.jpg" alt="Photo of thing" class="map" usemap="#houseMap" highlight>

  <map name="houseMap" id="map">
    <area ng-repeat="room in rooms" name="{{room.name}}" id="{{room.id}}" shape="poly" coords="{{room.coords}}" href="#/diagram/{{room.id}}" />
  </map>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `$route.reload()` and what's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: yep tried route.reload()

Comment: @NateHolmes Can you post more code? It sounds like the maphilight scripts aren't being re-run when you navigate back to the partial.

Comment: Can you show the controller code please?

Comment: yep please see edits @JohnDoe

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
If you are looking for a full refresh of the page.

```
 myApp.controller('DiagramController', ['$scope', '$route', 
                       '$http', '$window', function($scope, $route, $http, $window) {
    $http.get('js/master.json').success(function(data) {
       $scope.rooms = data;
       $scope.reloadPage = function(){
          $window.location.reload();         
        }
    });
    }]);
```

Comment: yeah I fixed the quotes around window but still no page refresh

Comment: that is correct but unfortunately that doesnt work either. I think what @JohnDoe said above is the issue and that the scripts arent being reloaded when i navigate back to that partial. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: <div class="main" ng-view> this line is in my index.html file if thats what you mean

Comment: Not sure but try this, `<div class="main"><div ng-view=""></div></div>`, if it doesn't work, reloading the scripts should be the issue!

Comment: add that in diagram.html?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be trying to reload the whole page - that's a sign that you're not achieving what you want to within the Angular system. What I'm saying is that you shouldn't be forcing pages to reload just to get a script to run. Do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-controller="yourContoller" data-ng-init="load();"></div>
```

JS:

```
.when('/example', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/example.html',
        controller  : 'yourController',
    })

app.controller('yourController', function($scope) {

$scope.load = function() { //PUT YOUR SCRIPTS HERE }

}
```

This way, the scripts will run every time the page loads, including the first time (and any subsequent time).

You could also use your existing directives in ng-onload's.

Comment: i made a jsfiddle just to make it easier to see the code in one place. Is this what you are suggesting? @JohnDoe http://jsfiddle.net/nateholmes3/pwu78t96/

Comment: @NateHolmes No, I'm suggesting using ng-init. I don't see that anywhere in the fiddle...

Comment: yes its in the html at the very top in the section tag

Comment: @NateHolmes That should be working then. Is it not? Why have you wrapped it in a get JSON success function? I would have thought it should be the other way around, the JSON success function inside the load function.

Comment: I had just had the JSON success function there first and didnt think it would make a difference but unfortunately it is not working. Do you mind posting the code for what youre suggesting? and can you confirm that the maphilight code is correct? sorry for bugging but thank you for all your help @JohnDoe

Comment: [I've updated the fiddle to illustrate what I mean](https://jsfiddle.net/pwu78t96/2/). It's not actually doing anything, so obviously I can't tell if it's working. I don't know anything about maphilight, but if it's working on pageload (and not working when you navigate back to that tab), then that part of the code isn't what you should be worrying about. @NateHolmes

Comment: No it still works on pageload but not when navigating back. If the script inside the load function is working correctly then I should be able to remove the directive that I created for hilight is that right? because once i remove that directive it no longer works on pageload @JohnDoe